# Вывод данных из БД с сравнением PHP и MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Помогите вывести значения из таблицы. перед этим сравнив их.
Допустим есть предложение:

*"сегодня сияло прекрасное EX_WORD, а вечером будет CD_WORD"*

и мне нужно вывести эти слова (Солнце, Вечером) из таблицы в предложение.

!!!То есть предложение после вывода должно выглядеть таким образом:
*"сегодня стояло прекрасное **СОЛНЦЕ**, а вечером будет **ДОЖДЬ**."*

Таблица выглядит таким образом:

```
-----------------------------------
 id  | name     | text
-------------------------------------
  1 | EX_WORD  |  солнце
  2 | CD_WORD  |  дождь
```

В таблице около 4000 строк (я показал на примере только 2 строки)

предложений тоже 4000 и куждого предложения  свои значения (не тольо солнце и дождь)

Comment: Самое простое решение на php получить из бд данные, разбить предложение на массив и дальше liner serach на совпадение, париться не хочешь array_intersect , полученное слово выделяешь. Если можно было бы менять таблицу, тогда hex и будет уже быстрее и все зависит от размера бд. Потому что также можно добавить сюда многопоточность. Так же можно отправлять запросы в бд и писать LIKE 'WORD', если предложение маленькое, какое решение оптимальнее для тебя, я просто все варианты расписывать не хочу

Comment: загрузи в ассоциативный массив, ключ - name, значение - text

Answer (score 2):

Вот одно из решений

```
<?php

$arrayFromBd = array('солнце', 'дождь');
$str = "сегодня стояло прекрасное СОЛНЦЕ, а вечером будет ДОЖДЬ.";
$strLower = mb_strtolower($str);
$matchWords = array_intersect(explode(' ', preg_replace('/[.,]/', '', $strLower)), $arrayFromBd);


$ind = 0;
foreach($matchWords as $val) {

    $str = substr_replace($str, "<b>".mb_strtoupper($val)."<b>", strpos($strLower, $val)+6*$ind) .
             substr($str, strpos($strLower, $val)+strlen($val)+6*$ind);

    $ind++;
}
echo $str;
// сегодня стояло прекрасное <b>СОЛНЦЕ<b>, а вечером будет <b>ДОЖДЬ<b>.
```

Или же сразу вытащить результат пример для запроса в бд

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE 
Column1 LIKE '%сегодня%'
OR Column1 LIKE '%стояло%'
OR Column1 LIKE  '%прекрасное%' ...
```

Также запрос с in

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE name in ('сегодня','стояло','прекрасное')
```

И вот про то что я комментировал

Сложный алгоритм для маленького массива ~1000

```
CPU times: user 4.56 ms, sys: 136 µs, total: 4.7 ms
Wall time: 4.09 ms
```

Простой алгоритм для маленького массива ~1000

```
CPU times: user 263 µs, sys: 63 µs, total: 326 µs
Wall time: 333 µs
```

Comment: таблица большая около 4000 разных строк.... это я привёл пример одной из строк таблицы....

Comment: можешь чуть по точнее не совсем понял, если в общем количество не достигает ~10k, сложные алгоритмы толком не нужны, ускорение будет заметно после 50k, ну это на примере python и то array_intersect терпит до ~15k, просто тот же python я замерял результат linear search, был быстрее в 14 раз до 1000, после же ~50k он просто загибался, а результат у второго алгоритма был чуть медленнее чем c ~1k, ну или же запрос с line или in, а дальше тестить что лучше тебе